# Github-like hosting, with private source, public ticketing system

Tags: git, github, version-control

I am in need of a site that offers the same services as Github (Git hosting, Ticketing, downloads, etc, etc) but allows me to have my source be private.

I don't mind paying if I can find these features, and I've already tried gitorious, unfuddled, and codebase. I also wouldn't mind hosting my own if the application already exists for this type of service.

Anyone have any ideas?

EDIT:

I understand that I could break them up into seperate projects, however, I would like to have them be within the same project if possible. That's really what I'm looking for.

Comment: Possible same but open: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11503246/how-to-have-a-private-repository-with-public-issue-tracker-on-github/31042410#31042410

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Github actually [offers private repositories](http://github.com/plans). I dont know if the included issue tracker can then be made public, but I suggest using a separate one anyway, like [Get Satisfaction](http://getsatisfaction.com/).

As [temoto points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1847875/github-like-hosting-with-private-source-public-ticketing-system/1847906#1847906), you need to break up the problem and use [the right tool for the right job](http://westciv.typepad.com/dog_or_higher/2004/05/the_right_tool_.html). It looks like you are looking for:

- Private [code hosting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_open_source_software_hosting_facilities) (I think you want a *Yes* in the *Private branch* column)
- Public [issue tracker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_issue_tracking_systems)
- Public [file host](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_hosting_services#Comparison_of_notable_file_hosting_services)

Those are links to comparison charts on Wikipedia, if you dont have any additional feature demands just browse around randomly and you probably discover what you like and dont like.

Comment: Why would you "suggest using a separate one" instead of using an integrated issue tracker?

Comment: I think the issue here was to have the repository private, but the issue tracker public. In Github a repository is either public or private, having both is not possible.

Answer (score 4):

Github's answer https://help.github.com/articles/issues-only-access-permissions

> Issues-only access permissions GitHub does not provide issues-only
>   access permissions, but you can accomplish this using a second
>   repository which contains only the issues.
>
> Create a private repository to host the source code from your project.
>   Create a second repository with the permissions you desire to host the
>   issue tracker. Add a README file to the issues repository explaining
>   the purpose of this repository and linking to the issues section. Set
>   your collaborators or teams to give access to the repositories as you
>   desire. Users with write access to both can reference and close Issues
>   back and forth across the repositories, but those without the required
>   permissions will see references that contain a minimum of information.
>
> For example, if you pushed a commit to the private repository's
>   default branch with a message that read Fixes
>   organization/public-repo#12, the issue would be closed, but only users
>   with the proper permissions would see the cross-repository reference
>   indicating the commit that closed the issue. Without the permissions,
>   a reference still appears, but the details are omitted.

Answer (score 3):

[Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/) (until now only known for Mercurial hosting) offers this: a private repository [can have a public ticketing system and wiki](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Making+your+Bitbucket+Issues+Private+or+Public).
Quote from the second link:

> **Separate settings for repository, wiki and issue tracker:** You can set your Bitbucket repository, wiki and issue tracker as private or public, independently of each other. For example, you can hide your code from the world by setting your repository as private, but let people see your documentation and issues by marking your wiki and issue tracker as public. Or you could set your repository and wiki as public but keep your issue tracker private. And so on.

Since Oct 03 '11, [Bitbucket offers Git hosting as well](http://blog.bitbucket.org/2011/10/03/bitbucket-now-rocks-git/) (same conditions as for HG hosting apply, and you can mix HG and Git repositories in the same account).

In the [free plan, you can have an unlimited number of private repositories](https://bitbucket.org/plans).
The only limitation in the free plan is that no more than 5 users can access your private repositories (if you want more, you have to pay).

Answer (score 1):

Bitbucket allows private repo but public issue tracking

Answer (score 0):

Break your need into two separate needs. First, you want a private code hosting; github has that. Second, you want a public ticketing; github has that. Just open two projects there.

Answer (score 0):

Github provides private repositories. See http://github.com/plans.